# mv command automatically running sometimes when opening a new prompt, throws error about renaming a `z` file

Tags: shell, zsh, prezto

I'm using Prezto for zsh, and sometimes when I open a new prompt this command automatically runs:

`mv: rename /Users/myusername/.z.19504 to /Users/myusername/.z: No such file or directory`

I do have the `z` package installed. Any idea why this is happening or how I can start to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *opening a new prompt*?

There are several ways in that Zsh runs something automatically: On starting a new shell, several startup files are executed (depending on how the shell is started). While running, a precmd could be defined which runs before each prompt is executed. The prompt string might have a command embedded. There other possibilities too.

I recommend starting a new shell with tracing enabled (`-x`) and analyze the output. This should show you, where the `mv` comes from.